# GUI using netbeans. Where to create ArrayList

Tags: java, netbeans

i am using netbeans to create my GUI.
I got the following class

- MainUI.java
- Person.java
- Gender.java (Enum)

Inside my MainUI.java are the codes auto generated by netbeans for my UI.

I want to create an ArrayList which will add a Person object into the arraylist when a JButton is clicked.

Where should i place the code `ArrayList<Person> list = new ArrayList<Person>();`?

`public class MainUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {`

OR

`public static void main(String args[]) {`.

If i put it in static void main, i could not access the arraylist from my eventhandler code in MainUI etends javax.swing.JFrame

Comment: Do not put too much logic inside UI classes. Separatation of concerns is good practice. My advice would be to create business classes independant of UI, pass a business object to the UI classes and let UI exchange with that object. But that is just my *opinion* so it cannot be an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a class where you store variables that should be accessed from anywhere in your program.

```
class Global {
    public static ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
    private Global(){}
}
```

You would access it like this:

```
GLobal.list.add(new Object());
```

Comment: even though its a working solution for the problem, far to many use this kind of approach far to often.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing what is implemented in each, I would suggest putting it in the `MainUI` class because it is being used every time a button is pressed and the button is implemented in the `MainUI`.